# Pegar atributo de requisição com Json em Python dá erro

Tags: python, flask

Tenho o seguinte código na minha aplicação em Flask:

```
from flask import request, json
cpf = request.json['cpf']
```

Ele funciona normalmente, mas quando não existe o atributo na requisição json ele apresenta o erro:

> builtins.KeyError
>   KeyError: 'cnpj_cpf'

E para a execução, a minha dúvida é como eu posso tratar dessa requisição para poder lançar uma response com o código 400 (Bad Request) dizendo que está faltando o atributo cpf, sem que aparece esse "erro de codificação"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro acontece pois  não existe o atributo "cnpj_cpf" na sua requisição, você pode trocar a chamada ao invés de usar chaves usar o método `get`, exemplo:

```py
cpf = request.json.get('cpf', None)
```

Nesse caso se não existir o atribuito cpf na request ele retorna `None` ai você pode dar uma response de Bad Request:

```
cpf = request.json.get('cpf', None)

if not cpf:
    return make_response('Informe o CPF', 400)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou 100% aqui, era o que precisava!

Answer (score 1):

Podes lidar com o erro do "KeyError" e lancar uma excepção com um 404. Fica algo deste genero:

```
try:
   cpf = request.json['cpf']
except KeyError:
   return render_template('404.html'), 404
```